# simple jQuery php json not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I got this in my html :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.post("mm.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" },
  function(data){
    $(data).each(function() {
    $("div").append($(this).name);
    });
  }, "json");
</script>

<div></div>
```

And my `mm.php` looks like this :

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("my" => array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm"), "ur"=>array("name"=>"Nah","time"=>"1:13")) ); ?>
```

This was working before i putted the `.each()` so doesnt have the including or other problems.

Why isnt this working ?
Where have i been going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is not a DOM element, it's a JSON object.  You need to use `$.each` instead of `.each()`  Also, inside the `each()`, `this` is an object, not a DOM element, so you don't need `$()` around it.

```
$.each(data, function() {
   $("div").append(this.name);
});
```

EDIT: Instead of using `this` inside the `each` try this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,v) {
   $("div").append(v.name);
});
```

Comment: @kritya: Because you were using `$()` around `data` and `this`.  This was converting them to jQuery objects, which just wrapped them in an array(-like) object.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$("div").append($(this).name);
```

Should be:

```
$("div").append(this.name);
```